# Input field for Tags separated by comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web application that allows users to post content by tags but the thing is, how would I make a nice block around a tag if its separated by a **comma** and the text field value would still be the same only the view to the user would differ.

An example would be such as YouTube or StackOverflow, for now I don't need it to check a database or anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Something similar like Stack Overflow does:

[image]

- Allows alphanumeric and `+-.#`  (and trims whitespaces!)
- Convert to lowercase
- Create automatically the Tag Box on *focusOut* <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd>  (add more delimited by `|` *pipe*)
- Delete Tag on click

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope.

  // TAGS BOX
  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig,''); // allowed characters
      if(txt) $("<span/>", {text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});
      this.value = "";
    },
    keyup(ev) {
      if(/(,|Enter)/.test(ev.key)) $(this).focusout(); 
    }
  });
  $("#tags").on("click", "span", function() {
    $(this).remove(); 
  });
  
});
```

```css
#tags{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:5px;
  font-family:Arial;
}
#tags > span{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  background:#789;
  padding:5px;
  padding-right:25px;
  margin:4px;
}
#tags > span:hover{
  opacity:0.7;
}
#tags > span:after{
 position:absolute;
 content:"×";
 border:1px solid;
 padding:2px 5px;
 margin-left:3px;
 font-size:11px;
}
#tags > input{
  background:#eee;
  border:0;
  margin:4px;
  padding:7px;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="tags">
  <span>php</span>
  <span>c++</span>
  <span>jquery</span>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: umm this doesn't really do the whole separate tags by comma thing... thanks for trying! I've plus oned the answer anyways.

Comment: @fermionoid added the comma thing :) take a look

Comment: I recommend a usage for an content-editable div.. its much easier I think

Comment: PERFECT, now i just need to implement this!

Comment: @fermionoid This is a very nice implementation, but it has practically no API. There is no way to retrieve tag values short of document traversal. Like I've said before, you don't really need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: hey it works on the jsBin demo but not when i try it: http://pastecan.com/v/jkO9jLb what have I done wrong? this script is the best so far. thanks!

Comment: @roXon, good job but it needs checking with IE8 as the remove function doesn't work within that

Comment: @Asad (thanks! :) ) but bro, in this 10 lines of jQ, it's a piece of cake to: after every event, store the current available tags into an array.

Comment: @fermionoid edited my answer. Always add the document ready function: `$(function(){ });` even if someone did not write it. (like me :) )

Comment: @Asad so what was the thing with IE8? I mean can i not just drop support for IE8?

Comment: @fermionoid no, look it's all fine with IE8 I used the pseudo selector `after` to create the [X] icons. you just create background images with an 'X' for those spans . that's it.

Comment: roXcon, i see what you are talking about but how would you implement the image? Could I just use text?

Comment: @fermionoid You would just have to change your markup slightly to `<span class="tag">JS<span class="delete">x</span></span>`. Then change `#tags span.tag:after` to `#tags span.tag .delete`.

Comment: no, use an image background and use background-position: right top; to place it at the right. I downloaded the demo and tested in IE8 ... looks like @Asad is in panic. Works perfectly like it is. Just online jsBin on IE8 is buggy.

Comment: If you need to store the values I can help you with this too.

Comment: @roXcon what do you mean? and, im really sorry but i'm still a bit confused about the whole IE8 thing...

Comment: @roXon I never said the demo didn't work, I was just trying to help by pointing out a simple workaround for `:after` (using a real element instead of a pseudo element). The OP tagged me for some reason regarding IE8 (even though I wasn't the one who mentioned it)

Comment: @Asad but what if I have no default tags then i would have to edit the JS too, right?

Comment: :) Asad download the jsBin and open in IE8. works great, there are even the 'X' just without borders, so I suggest to use BG images with 'X' icon, cause the entire <span> is clickable. So for a XBrowser perfect result best use BG image.

Comment: @fermionoid No, the JS works regardless of your markup I believe. roXon knows best though.

Comment: @Asad, ok i'll leave it the way it is for now.

Comment: No, as you can see I put some default tags right into the HTML. just remove them. It's so obvious :)

Comment: I know i'm gonna sound picky but how would I get the tags to be deleted on backspace? so if the input field is empty, and I hit the backspace, it will remove the last tag. How would I edit the code to do this?

Comment: @fermionoid You can easily just extend the keyup listener with other keycodes. If the keycode is backspace, you remove the last tag element.

Comment: hey now, im facing issues with actually processing the tags in a POST request.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/iyewas/5/edit (this one will use a tag name inside the Confirm box)

Comment: When I put the text field in a form and assign a name attribute to it, i get nothing out of it.

Comment: right, cause the text field is empty, you need to loop all `.tag` element's `.text()` and store in array or string

Comment: umm how would I do this, could I store it in a div? please show me how!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21869/discussion-between-fermionoid-and-roxon)

Comment: the solution with backspace is not so good, cause every backspace you hit on your page will try to remove the tag. ... your choice

Comment: @roXon, i'll try to figure the backspace part out myself, if I cannot, I'll ask you.

Comment: What a great answer! Thanks!

Comment: This adds duplicate tags .. Maybe you want to add it and make it perfect `;-)`

Comment: how can i use the tags as values at input fields to submit?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan can you please update your answer,
how can I retrieve all spans (ie values)  when `form` submitted by `jquery` or `js`

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh on form submit, get an Array of values using: `const tags = $("#tags span").get().map(el => el.textContent);`

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh or rather, on init and on change, modify the value of a hidden input. Send that input value to the server, and on server-side split the value by comma to get your array: `"c++, php, javascript"` to get `["c++", "php", "javascript"]` as desired. (And don't forget to trim whitespaces as well.)

Answer (score 8):

You don't necessarily need to reinvent the wheel here. A number of libraries/plugins for this purpose already exist, one of which is Guillermo Rauch's [TextboxList](http://www.devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist/). You can find a demonstration [here](http://www.devthought.com/wp-content/projects/mootools/textboxlist/Demo/). It already has autocomplete support and a pretty extensive API, which is what the major hurdles in any implementation of this are going to be.

The original implementation used MooTools, but you can find a jQuery version by golive [here](https://github.com/golive/TextboxList).

Comment: c'mon you're killing all the fun

Comment: @roXon Don't get me wrong, I upvoted your answer, but it is purely visual. It would still take some work to make an API that allows convenient access to data, but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @fermionoid I haven't personally used that one, but you could try that as well. My point is basically that you don't really need to write a bunch of code and debug edge cases when that has already been done for you.

Comment: True, i do understand your point, i've upvoted your answer and what's wrong with my implementation: http://pastecan.com/v/jkO9jLb ?

Comment: nevermind, i think i found my answer to the implementation :)

Comment: @fermionoid Your script appears before the elements it is referring to are loaded. Either use a `ready` handler or put your script at the end of the document.

Comment: Do note that for commercial use the TextBoxList requires a $20 fee. Not a bad fee by any means, but folks should be aware of that prior to haphazardly pasting it in to their code base. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Put a text input within a div, then check for keypresses (such as the comma or space key), if it matches the key append a new span with the tag details to the div with jQuery.

I can provide more detail or an example if needed but it should be fairly straightforward to code.

Comment: ok, I see where you are going, but can you show me an example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @fermionoid: Why don't you try making it first?

Comment: @Blender, what I don't quite understand is how the div will affect the textarea, i thought that a text area couldn't have individual styles in it and also I don't really get the javascript behind it, it's more advanced that what i usually do in js.

Comment: @fermionoid: Make a fake textarea out of a `<div>` tag and make the textbox completely unstyled.

Comment: @fermionoid, Roxon has provided a good starting example for you. That example doesn't function exactly how you want yours to but it should help you get underway. If you're still having trouble come back with your code and I'll be happy to help out

Comment: @MattG I recommend also for using a contenteditable div.. what do you think about that?

Comment: @manhan but what about html5 support? shalli just drop non-html5 browsers?

Comment: @Mahan In my opinion that could also work equally as well yes

Comment: ill try to write something, ill be back with the results, thanks Matt

Comment: @fermionoid, if you're worried about html5 support with older IE browsers try a google search for html5shiv

Comment: @fermionoid no you must not, this is simple as MattG explained to you

Comment: The thing i don't get is how the javascript will work and how it will style the textfield, sorry, i just dont understand.

Comment: guys, I was in hurry, added the comma thing :)

Comment: @fermionoid Go with roXon's example, it works and is easily customizable via the CSS to match the look you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Tagging Support" in select2 lists:
https://select2.github.io/examples.html

```
    $(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make a tag box like Facebook uses for tagging people, and found the available options to be bloated and/or not do a key thing I wanted: Require the tag exist in a preset list (which can be retrieved from an AJAX call.

I started with [Roko C. Buljan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14083331/3917091) and then added a few important things.

- Arrow key navigation
- Requiring preset answers, as I said above
- `data-` attributes for easy gathering for a ajax-post.

[Codepen for anyone interested](https://codepen.io/bracketsage/pen/XzOJKo)