# How to format text in an input text field

Tags: html, css

I am making an application similar to stackoverflow.com For posting a question we add tags, I want to know that how do I change style of text after typing comma.

Comment: You should share the code, or any test cases you tried, so closing your question unless you share your code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a “tags box” using jQuery (with text input field + tags separated by comma)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083272/how-to-make-a-tags-box-using-jquery-with-text-input-field-tags-separated-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to use JS for that.**

This is how the logic would look like.Its just a base template to get you started.

```
<input type="text" onchange="tagit()" id="tags" />
<script>
function tagit(){
  var tags=$("#tags").val() //get the value of the input tag.
  // break the tags based on comma
  // wrap each tag around a <span> element
  // style the <span> element
}
</script>
```

You can also check out **.change()** event in jQuery **http://api.jquery.com/change/**