# Get tags value in "tag box" created in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, tags

I came across this [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083272/how-to-make-a-tags-box-using-jquery-with-text-input-field-tags-separated-by), and I basically copied the code (html, css and jquery) to my web page. Everything works except that I don't know how to get the tags when my html form is submitted.

From my understanding of the javascript code, the tags are stored in   tags, they are not stored in  fields, so my question is how to capture those tags when the form where it's embedded is submitted?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean you can't get the list of tags already added when form submitting?

Comment: right, the tags are like this <span class="tag">php</span>, how to get the value "php" when the form is submitted? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate a jquery object and get the child's content in this way:

```
var tags = '';
$('#tags > span').each(function() {
    tags = tags + $(this).html() + ',';
});
$('#inputInForm').val(tags);
```

Comment: thanks, does it push all the tags to an <input> field with id of "tags" so that my form can submit the data to handler?

Comment: @TonyGW I edited my answer, tags will be append to a string and split with `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a hidden input field to each of your tags like this when you create them:

```
<span class="tag">
    tag-name
    <input type="hidden" name="tags[]" value="tag-name">
</span>
```

This way you will automatically get the tags array when you post the form (obviously those tags should be within your `form`).