# How to display tags in a HTML textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am rather curious.

When a member is asking a question in Stack Overflow, within a textbox, the member can enter tags which will change into a  graphical form automatically. There is even an 'X' button to the side of each tag which will allow the tag to be deleted.

How is this implemented in HTML? I thought only pure text is allowed in a textbox.

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896773/jquery-plugins-to-enter-multiple-email-in-single-input

Comment: Actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083272/how-to-make-a-tags-box-using-jquery-with-text-input-field-tags-separated-by

Comment: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

Comment: Thank you, guys, for all your comments! Please give me some time to review your solutions before I accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag system is quite easy to do with a jquery library. Check these out:

- http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/
- https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

Only text is allowed in a textfield, you're right.

The Tags field, when you're asking a question on this site, is actually a `<div>` which looks like a textfield. Then, it's a matter of CSS and JavaScript to manage inserting and removing the tags. You could use web-inspector to study the HTML structure and css/js codes.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing source of the tags may give some idea:

[image]