# Creating a tag box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a tag box similar to that of StackOverflow. I see that this question has already been asked here ([How to make a "tags box" using jQuery (with text input field + tags separated by comma)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083272/how-to-make-a-tags-box-using-jquery-with-text-input-field-tags-separated-by)) but I'm having a question with regards to the Javascript.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class='tag-container' id = "tag-container">
      <span class='dashfolio-tag'>Tag1</span>
      <span class='dashfolio-tag'>Tag2</span>
      <span class='dashfolio-tag'>Tag3</span>
  </div>      


 <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" id = "add-tag-input" />
```

CSS:

```
.tag-container {
max-width: 300px; /* helps wrap the tags in a specific width */

}

.dashfolio-tag {
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 3px; /*incase tags go in next line, will space */
  color:#fff;
  background:#789;
  padding-right: 20px; /* adds space inside the tags for the 'x' button */
}

.dashfolio-tag:hover{
  opacity:0.7;
}

.dashfolio-tag:after { 

 position:absolute;
 content:"×";
 padding:2px 2px;
 margin-left:2px;
 font-size:11px;
}

#add-tag-input {
  background:#eee;
  border:0;
  margin:6px 6px 6px 0px ; /* t r b l */
  padding:5px;
  width:auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){ 

  $("#add-tag-input").on({
    focusout : function() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig,''); // allowed characters
      if(txt) $("<span/>", {text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});


      this.value = "";
    },
    keyup : function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if(/(188|13)/.test(ev.which)) $(this).focusout(); 
    }
  });
  $('.tag-container').on('click', 'span', function() {
    if(confirm("Remove "+ $(this).text() +"?")) $(this).remove(); 
  });

});

});
```

My question is pretty simple, how do I add the new input as a span with class `dashfolio-tag` inside the `#tag-container`? I dabbled with the `insertBefore` property trying to add it to the right node, but to no avail.  Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Just checking, why not use a library which is already there? e.g. [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line of code,

```
if(txt) $("<span/>", {text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});
```

to

```
if(txt) {
    $("<span/>", {
        text:txt.toLowerCase(),
        appendTo:"#tag-container",
        class:"dashfolio-tag"
    });
}
```

See the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2gvdsvos/4/

---

To fix the margins in between tags,

Update HTML to,

```
<div>
  <div class="tag-container" id="tag-container">
    <span class='dashfolio-tag'>tag1</span>
    <span class='dashfolio-tag'>tag2</span>
    <span class='dashfolio-tag'>tag3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" id="add-tag-input" />
</div>
```

And add this to CSS,

```
.tag-container:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

.dashfolio-tag {
  ...
  margin-right: 4px;
  float: left;
}
```

Hope this helps! ;)

https://jsfiddle.net/2gvdsvos/5/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a million! I noticed that adding 2 additional tags to the existing ones messes up the margins, and this is true within my app as well. I checked the HTML source and it all looks correct. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That because inline elements has a default white spacing in between (this cause by default font-size rendering on inline elements). so you have to add the elements without new lines/spacers or use different methods to tackle it. e.g. float child elements