# How to refresh an Input field after changing its value with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Input element in HTML (and a Javascript template) with empty Value. Throught AJAX and JQuery, I update the said value to a list of words split by comma. Each word should become green retangulars with an 'X' to remove it from the field. The same list of words works perfectly when I write it down in the code.

The problem is that when I put this very same string in the Value attrib. using JQuery, it just doesn't work properly. I just get plain text, and those fancy green retangulars only appear when I click inside the input field and hit TAB key. Then They become one item only and when I finally click to remove it, then they got split(!).

I have already tried using fadeOut() and fadeIn() and refresh method. Did not work.

Any ideas about this?

## HTML:

```
<input id="tags_1" type="text" class="tags form-control" value="" />
```

## AJAX/JQUERY:

```
var tags_x = tags_x.replace(/\,/g, ', ');
var tags_x = tags_x.split(',');

$('#tags_1').val(tags_x);
$('#tags_1').attr('value', tags_x);
$('#tags_1').fadeOut();
$('#tags_1').fadeIn();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a tag box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482063/creating-a-tag-box)

Answer (score 0):

Your id of the input is `tags_1` but you are selecting it like `#tags_1_tag`. Why is that? I think maybe that could be the reason.

And by the way when you use `var tags_x = tags_x.split(',');` tags_x is an array now. If you want to put it in a value convert it to a string and then try to put it in the value attr. You can see an example below:

```
var new_x = tags_x.join('')
$('#tags_1_tag').val(new_x);
```

Comment: Actually I keep having the problem. That was a mytyping in one of my tries and fixing the ID unfortunately does not solve the issue.