# replacing text with a div inside a div with content editable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: here]

does anyone know what is this called? I want to create a similar function in my app but I don't know what it's called to be able to search for ways of how to do it.

I created a div with content editable then added an onInput event

```js
  function onStateAddHandler(e){
    let wordArray = []
    const words = e.target.innerText.split(',').filter(word => word.trim() != '')
    words.forEach(word => {
        const filteredWord = word.replace(/\s/g, '')

        wordArray.push(filteredWord)
    })
    setStates(wordArray)
   }
```

after that I tried to create a div, add the text to it and append it to the div with content editable using the ref like so:

```js
  function onStateAddHandler(e){
    let wordArray = []
    const words = e.target.innerText.split(',').filter(word => word.trim() != '')
    words.forEach(word => {
        const filteredWord = word.replace(/\s/g, '')

        let div = document.createElement('div')
        let content = document.createTextNode(filteredWord)

        div.append(content)

        statesDiv.current.appendChild(div)
        wordArray.push(filteredWord)
    })
    setStates(wordArray)
   }
```

but I end up with this disastrous output, and I think this is happening because the appended div is also then getting filtered with my function then getting pushed to the array, but honestly I've been trying since morning to find a way and nothing worked any idea?
[image]

Comment: This is a *"Tags Field"* (but you're welcome to coin a better name if you will), pure Elements inside an Element that are created (like you guessed right) by taking an input value and on `blur` creating those elements. See more (a jQuery version) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083272/input-field-for-tags-separated-by-comma/14083331#14083331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is called `multi select` or `multi select tag`. If you are using react, you may have a look at [`react-select`](https://react-select.com/home).

Comment: thank you, I just tried react-select and it works like a charm, and I did get results from youtube incase I want to create it on my own ( ^ ^ )