# How to create Tags functionality of a forum same as stackoverflow?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I am creating a forum in asp.net from sketch.Every thing is done in right manner but I got stuck in "Tag" feature of forum.I have completed database things for "Tag" feature. I just want same functionality as StackOverflow is using. When we ask any question in stackoverflow It asks for "Tags" and when we type in this textbox it fetches lookup tags from database. I want to know which control they are using inside the textbox which gives to remove tag functionality(cross or 'x' symbol), tag list, comma and space separator.I fell it would be some ajax control or Jquery but I am not sure. I would like to repeat once again that I am all clear about database table things.

Please guide me with ur kind knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO - CREATE TAGS](http://jsbin.com/iyomus/6/edit)**</kbd>
<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO - CREATED TAGS ANIMATIONS](http://jsbin.com/ihuhip/1/edit)**</kbd>

*Take a look at my answers here:*
[How to make tag text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383634/how-to-make-tag-text-box)
[What type of animation does StackOverflow use for Tag Popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200320/what-type-of-animation-does-stackoverflow-use-for-tag-popup)

Comment: Thanks roXon. That is what I was looking for. Let me go through the above links. Thanks a lot once again.